# How to read a JSON file in Java? with the JSON.simple library

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON text. How can I read it?

{"animal": {
  "type": "Panther",
  "name": "Sylvester",
  "age": 12
}}

I've tried to do this but it doesn't work.

It throws this Exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray at Json_to_XML.main(Json_to_XML.java:31)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':Json_to_XML.main()'.
Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            //JSON parser object to parse read file
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            try {
                String ruta ="C:\\Users\\Usuari\\Desktop\\documento.json";
                Object obj = jsonParser.parse (new FileReader (ruta));

                JSONObject jsonObject  = (JSONObject) obj;

                String tipo = (String) jsonObject.get("type");
                System.out.println(tipo);

                String nombre = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
                System.out.println(nombre);

                Long edad = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
                System.out.println(edad);

                JSONArray leng= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("animal");
                Iterator iterator =leng.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please explain ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? It throws an Exception? A line is unresolved? The result is different from expected? Please try to be more clear

Comment: What do you expect `jsonObject.get("tipo")` to return? There is no `tipo` key in JSON you provided. Same about other keys.

Comment: It throws this Exception    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
 at Json_to_XML.main(Json_to_XML.java:31)

Comment: `{}` represents object, `[]` represents array. `"animal": { .. }` holds object and that is what `jsonObject.get("animal")` returns. You can't cast it to array (I don't know why would you even want to).

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible way of solving your issue:

**You** can convert object in .json into array, you will need to change this:

```
{"animal": { "type": "Panther", "name": "Sylvester", "age": 12 }}
```

To that:

```
{"animal": [{"type": "Panther", "name": "Sylvester", "age": 12 }]}
```

**Unless** you want to keep json intact, then consider the following change from:

```
JSONArray leng= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("animal");
Iterator iterator =leng.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

To:

```
JSONObject leng= (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("animal");
System.out.println(leng.get("name") + " - " + leng.get("type"));
```